# PHP Echo specific column multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, echo

I'm experimenting with a multidimensional array in PHP with strings as values. I want to echo all the values of one single column, instead of all values of all columns.

First i create the array!

```
$test = array
(
  array("hoge", "bomen", "vangen"),
  array("moeten", "we", "rekening"),
  array("voor", "deze", "tijd")
  );    ``
```

This foreach outputs all the values!

```
foreach ($test as $val) {

    echo "$val" . "<br/>";
    }
```

How can i output only the values of column 2? instead of the values of all the columns.

I want this output:

```
bomen
we
deze
```

Comment: Please post what the expected output would be in this example

Comment: `echo $val[0]` for the first one, etc...

Comment: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works :D (Welcome on SO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$test = array(
          array("hoge", "bomen", "vangen"),
          array("moeten", "we", "rekening"),
          array("voor", "deze", "tijd")
        );   

               //vv Go trough each innerArray
foreach($test as $v) 
    echo $v[1] . "<br />";
       //^^^^^ Print the second element of each innerArray
```

Output:

```
bomen
we
deze
```

Also for more information about arrays see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (The manual is always a good reference to search for things and learn it :D)

Comment: @Fille You're welcome! Enjoy your day :D (FYI: If you have a php problem just do a quick google search with keywords of the problem, search it in the manual (php.net) and or try a little bit debugging :D)

Comment: @Fille [Click here and read this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223142/php-echo-specific-column-multi-dimensional-array#comment44837289_28223142) left under your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to display the elements of the first inner array, then

```
foreach($test[0] as $value) echo $value."\n";
```

Comment: I think he wants the first element of EVERY inner array.

Comment: i think its 50\50 between the two possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$test2 = array_map( 
                    function($element){ 
                        return $element[0]; 
                    },  
                    $test 
          );
```

`$element[0]` is the element you want it from each array,
and do a foreach for $test2 or print inside closure.

*Or use:*

```
$arr = array_column($test, 0);
```

`0` is the index key you want to keep. do a foreach on $arr.

Answer (score 0):

This code can solve the problem:

```
$test = array
(
  array("hoge", "bomen", "vangen"),
  array("moeten", "we", "rekening"),
  array("voor", "deze", "tijd")
  );
  for($i=0; $i<count($test);$i++) {
    echo $test[$i][1];
}
```

If foreach is not your choice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what do you mean by column, but this is probably what you are looking for

```
$column = 0;
foreach ($test as $val) {
    echo $val[$column];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prints the value for the column number, which is set in the `$column` variable.

```
<?php
    $test = array(
        array("hoge", "bomen", "vangen"),
        array("moeten", "we", "rekening"),
        array("voor", "deze", "tijd")
    );

    $column = 1; // number of the column you want
    array_map(function($v) use ($column) {
        echo $v[$column-1] . " ";
    },$test);
?>
```